# Service Builder is giving error with life-ray 7

Tags: liferay-7, liferay-service-builder

I'm working on Liferay 7. I'm new to Liferay and I'm experiencing an issue that I spent too much time on.

I have a portlet that I decided to create a Service Builder (named "Employee"). Here is my service.xml :

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE service-builder PUBLIC "-//Liferay//DTD Service Builder 7.0.0//EN" "http://www.liferay.com/dtd/liferay-service-builder_7_0_0.dtd">
<service-builder package-path="com.test">
    <author>sachin.singh</author>
    <namespace>crud</namespace>

    <entity name="Employee" table="user" local-service="true" remote-service="true">
        <column name="iduser" type="int" primary="true" id-type="increment"/>
        <column name="name" type="String" />
        <column name="secret_code" type="String" />
    </entity>
</service-builder>
```

And when i am building using liferay service builder i am getting this error

```
  [copy] Copying 1 file to D:\tools\com.liferay.portal.plugins.sdk-1.0.11\portlets\firstLiferay-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\classes
     [copy] Copied 3 empty directories to 2 empty directories under D:\tools\com.liferay.portal.plugins.sdk-1.0.11\portlets\firstLiferay-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\classes
      [jar] Building MANIFEST-only jar: D:\tools\com.liferay.portal.plugins.sdk-1.0.11\portlets\firstLiferay-portlet\service-builder-classpath.jar
   [delete] Deleting: D:\tools\com.liferay.portal.plugins.sdk-1.0.11\portlets\firstLiferay-portlet\service-builder-classpath.jar.manifest
     [java] Java Result: 1
   [delete] Deleting: D:\tools\com.liferay.portal.plugins.sdk-1.0.11\portlets\firstLiferay-portlet\service-builder-classpath.jar
     [echo] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/thoughtworks/qdox/model/JavaMethod
     [echo]     at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
     [echo]     at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
     [echo]     at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
     [echo]     at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
     [echo]     at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
     [echo]     at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
     [echo]     at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
     [echo] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.thoughtworks.qdox.model.JavaMethod
     [echo]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
     [echo]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
     [echo]     at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
     [echo]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
     [echo]     ... 7 more
     [echo] Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
     [echo] Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=512m; support was removed in 8.0
     [echo] Exception in thread "main"
```

I checked and cross verify,All jars are there in jar library.

Here is the screenshot of added jar:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Especially when you're new, I'd recommend to try again and use Liferay Workspace instead of the (deprecated) plugins-sdk. All of the samples ([here's one for service builder](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-blade-samples/tree/master/liferay-workspace/apps/service-builder)) build on this, and plugins-sdk should largely be used only to migrate existing legacy plugins to the latest release.

I'm not sure what your screenshot shows - if it's all of the bundled jars, then it looks horrible. You should only have tiny plugins in times of OSGi bundles, and it definitely looks like those are way too many dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for the reply  @Olaf Kock
  
Yes,This is my bundled jar but that came from sdk-plugin i did not add manually.Will try to reduce :-)

Comment: I have added all jars in WEB-INF/lib now that error is vanished.Now i am getting this error **Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: freemarker.template.Configuration.getVersion()Lfreemarker/template/Version;** do you think i have to post another question?